# Keep getting 'existing email' error in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to setup a method to allow users to login to their Firebase accounts using Facebook. If it is a first time user creating an account everything works fine, but if a user made an account before and is trying to login in to their account is where the trouble begins. When the code

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: {(user, error)
```

runs I get the error saying that the email is already in use, even though it is the account in which they are trying to sign in for.

My entire code is here:

```
func handleCustomFBLogin() {
    FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("Error loggin in is \(err)")
            //self.facebookanimateIn()
        } else if (result?.isCancelled)!{
            print("The user cancelled loggin in ")
        } else {
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
                            let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"])
            graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if ((error) != nil) {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                } else {

                    let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String: AnyObject]
                    let facebookName:NSString =  data["name"] as! NSString

                    let facebookEmail = data["email"] as Any

                    let userId = data["id"] as! NSString
                    let facebookProfileUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userId)/picture?type=large"
                    let facebookAge = data["age_range"] as Any
                    let password = "needToPutRandomizedPasswordInHere" as String
                    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: facebookEmail as! String, password: password, completion: {result, error in
                        if error != nil{
                            //user has account, they just need to sign in
                            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: {(user, error) in
                                if error != nil{
                                    print(error.debugDescription)
                                    return
                                }

                                let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
                                let vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "checker") as! UINavigationController
                                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                               // ref.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
                            })
                        } else {
                            //user does not have an account and they need to create one
                            guard let uid = result?.uid else{
                                return
                            }
                            print("user created as \(uid)")
                            let val = "0"
                            let number = (val as NSString).integerValue
                            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
                            let usersReference = ref.child("Users").child(uid)
                            let values = [""] as [String : Any];
                            usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err,ref) in
                                if err != nil {
                                    print(err.debugDescription)
                                    return}})
                            print("Save the user successfully into Firebase database")
                            let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
                            let vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "checker") as! UINavigationController
                            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to create the user when signing in with a credential token

Comment: I'm using the create the user to check if the user has created an account before. So if an error comes up it shows that the user has an account already @Callam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you have created the user, all you need is the login step

```
 FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            // handle errors
        } else {
            // continue with login process
        }
    })
```

Comment: I can do this even though it is a Facebook user logging in ?

Comment: you are using the Facebook credentials to create a new user in Firebase - you don't need to add a new user every time they log in.  Better, I think, to reverse your logic - try to log in, and if that fails, consider creating an account.  Users will only be new once, but will be returning many times